# Rails 5 - How to revert/delete the already broadcasted notification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, broadcast, actioncable

In rails 5, I am using `ActionCable` for broadcast notification in real-time basis. Broadcast is happening once `Notification` object is created. Right now I want to revert back the broadcasted notification when `Notification` object get deleted.

In notification_broadcast_job.rb,

```
def perform(notification, user_id)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "notifications:#{user_id}", data: NotificationSerializer.new(notification)
end
```

In notification.rb,

```
after_commit :broadcast_notification

private

def broadcast_notification
  users.each do |user|
    NotificationsBroadcastJob.perform_later(self, user.id)
  end
end
```

Now issue is like, when user A likes one post which belongs to user B then B will get notification (without page reload). When user A unlikes it immediately then notification should go off from user B (without page reload). Right now deleted object (notification) will simply shows in a list.

How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

What your problem is that you can't disdinguish whether the object `Notification` was created or deleted ?

You can use `after_create` and `after_destroy` instead of `after_commit`

The back-end pass data to front-end, then front-end will show or hide data. The key is that font-end need to know whether show or hide. So there should be a protocol between back and front. There is none-elegant example:

In notification.rb,

```
after_create :broadcast_notification
after_destroy :delete_notification
private

def broadcast_notification
  users.each do |user|
    NotificationsBroadcastJob.perform_later(self,'created', user.id)
  end
end

def delete_notification
  users.each do |user|
    NotificationsBroadcastJob.perform_later(self,'delete', user.id)
  end
end
```

In notification_broadcast_job.rb,

```
def perform(notification, message_type , user_id)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "notifications:#{user_id}", data:{ message_type: message_type, info: {id: notification.id, body: notification.body}}
end
```

The front-end will read the `message_type` first. Then it know show or hide something.

front-end js code:

```
if(data.message_type == 'created'){
  $('***').append('<li id=' + data.info.id + '>' + data.info.body +'</li>'); // 
}else{
  $('#'+ data.info.id).hide();
}
```

Comment: What should I do in `after_destroy` method ?

Comment: Can you be more elaborate?

Comment: There is already a broadcast related methods are written under `after_commit`. How should I write its reverted(broadcast) code in `after_destroy`?